# Build a stamp duty calculator for various types of buyers

Tags: javascript, interview-questions, calculator

I had a task where I had to build a stamp duty calculator, which calculates the tax or stamp duty first-time buyers(`ftb`) returning buyers (`rtb`), and second-home buyers (`shb`) had to pay when purchasing the home.

These were the tax bands, although I think some of the percentages may be slightly wrong.

```
First Time Buyers
0 to £300,000 - 0%
£300,001 to £925,000 - 5%
£925001 to £1,500,000 - 10%
£1,500,000 and above - 12%

Returning Buyers
0 to £125,000 - 0%
£125,001 to £250,000 - 2%
£250,001 to £925,000 - 5%
£925,001 to £1,500,000 - 10%
£1,500,000 and above - 12%

Second Home Buyers
0 to £125,000 - 3%
£125,001 to £250,000 - 5%
£250,001 to £925,000 - 8%
£925,001 to £1,500,000 - 13%
£1,500,000 and above - 15%
```

Here is my solution, I look forward to the feedback.

```
const stampDutyCalc = (price) => {
  let stampdutyObject = {
    ftb: 0,
    rtb: 0,
    shb: 0,
  };

  firstTimeBuyerCalc(price, stampdutyObject);
  returningBuyerCalc(price, stampdutyObject);
  secondHomeBuyerCalc(price, stampdutyObject);

  return stampdutyObject;
};

function firstTimeBuyerCalc(price, stampdutyObject) {
  if (price <= 300000) {
    stampdutyObject.ftb += 0;
  } else if (price > 300000 && price <= 925000) {
    stampdutyObject.ftb += price * 0.05;
  } else if (price > 925000 && price <= 1500000) {
    stampdutyObject.ftb += (price - 925000) * 0.1 + (925000 - 300000) * 0.05;
  } else {
    stampdutyObject.ftb +=
      (price - 1500000) * 0.12 +
      (1500000 - 925000) * 0.1 +
      (925000 - 300000) * 0.05;
  }
}

function returningBuyerCalc(price, stampdutyObject) {
  if (price <= 125000) {
    stampdutyObject.rtb += 0;
  } else if (price > 125000 && price <= 250000) {
    stampdutyObject.rtb += price * 0.02;
  } else if (price > 250000 && price <= 925000) {
    stampdutyObject.rtb += (price - 250000) * 0.05 + (250000 - 125000) * 0.02;
  } else if (price > 925000 && price <= 1500000) {
    stampdutyObject.rtb +=
      (price - 925000) * 0.1 +
      (925000 - 250000) * 0.05 +
      (250000 - 125000) * 0.02;
  } else {
    stampdutyObject.rtb +=
      (price - 1500000) * 0.12 +
      (1500000 - 925000) * 0.1 +
      (925000 - 250000) * 0.05 +
      (250000 - 125000) * 0.02;
  }
}

function secondHomeBuyerCalc(price, stampdutyObject) {
  if (price <= 125000) {
    stampdutyObject.shb = price * 0.03;
  } else if (price > 125000 && price <= 250000) {
    stampdutyObject.shb += (price - 125000) * 0.05 + 125000 * 0.03;
  } else if (price > 250000 && price <= 925000) {
    stampdutyObject.shb +=
      (price - 250000) * 0.08 + (250000 - 125000) * 0.05 + 125000 * 0.03;
  } else if (price > 925000 && price <= 1500000) {
    stampdutyObject.shb +=
      (price - 925000) * 0.13 +
      (925000 - 250000) * 0.08 +
      (250000 - 125000) * 0.05 +
      125000 * 0.03;
  } else {
    stampdutyObject.shb +=
      (price - 1500000) * 0.15 +
      (1500000 - 925000) * 0.13 +
      (925000 - 250000) * 0.08 +
      (250000 - 125000) * 0.0 +
      125000 * 0.03;
  }
}

function returningBuyerCalc(price, stampdutyObject) {
  if (price <= 125000) {
    stampdutyObject.rtb += 0;
  } else if (price > 125000 && price <= 250000) {
    stampdutyObject.rtb += price * 0.02;
  } else if (price > 250000 && price <= 925000) {
    stampdutyObject.rtb += (price - 250000) * 0.05 + (250000 - 125000) * 0.02;
  } else if (price > 925000 && price <= 1500000) {
    stampdutyObject.rtb +=
      (price - 925000) * 0.1 +
      (925000 - 250000) * 0.05 +
      (250000 - 125000) * 0.02;
  } else {
    stampdutyObject.rtb +=
      (price - 1500000) * 0.12 +
      (1500000 - 925000) * 0.1 +
      (925000 - 250000) * 0.05 +
      (250000 - 125000) * 0.02;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your bands are way wrong at present, because there’s no stamp duty (if you’re not buying a second home) up to £500,000, until 31 March next year. There’s also a 15% rate for some residential property purchases by corporations.

Comment: @MikeScott the bands were given as part of the task. Which why I mentioned that I think some of the percentages are incorrect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Hard coded

You have created yourself a future problem by hard coding the data in your code.  When dealing with taxes (or any business logic)  there is one certainty, and that is *change*.

With the data embedded in the code, making even a minor change will take some effort and will be very prone to error.

You need to create a data structure that allows you to make changes quickly and easily. You should only have to change a value once, in one location, not many times in many places.

### Defining the data

The data is defined as an object, with only the data needed, if information can be deduced there is no need to include it.

The example has a helper function `rate` to reduce the overhead of typing in `{level:10000, tax: 0.1}` over and over

```
const rate = (level, tax) => ({level, tax});
const brackets = {
    firstTime: [
        rate(300000, 0),
        rate(925000, 0.05),
        rate(1500000, 0.1),
        rate(Infinity, 0.12),
    ],
    returning: [
        rate(125000, 0),
        rate(250000, 0.02),
        rate(925000, 0.05),
        rate(1500000, 0.1),
        rate(Infinity, 0.12),   
    ],
    second: [
        rate(125000, 0.03),
        rate(250000, 0.05),
        rate(925000, 0.08),
        rate(1500000, 0.13),
        rate(Infinity, 0.15),       
    ],
};
```

#### Applying logic

With the data organised, the code can then just deal with the logic of how the duty is calculated:

```
function calculateDuty(price, bracket) {
    var duty = 0;
    var prevLevel = 0
    for (const rate of bracket) {
        if (rate.level <= price) {
            duty += (rate.level - prevLevel) * rate.tax;
            prevLevel = rate.level;
        } else {
            return duty + (price - prevLevel) * rate.tax;
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can get the duty for any bracket: `calculateDuty(price, brackets.firstTime)`

### Rewrite

Thus the whole thing becomes:

```
const rate = (level, tax) => ({level, tax});
const brackets = {
    firstTime: [rate(300000, 0), rate(925000, 0.05), rate(1500000, 0.1), rate(Infinity, 0.12)],
    returning: [rate(125000, 0), rate(250000, 0.02), rate(925000, 0.05), rate(1500000, 0.1), rate(Infinity, 0.12)],
    second: [rate(125000, 0.03), rate(250000, 0.05), rate(925000, 0.08), rate(1500000, 0.13), rate(Infinity, 0.15)],
};
const stampDutyCalc = price => ({  
    ftb: calculateDuty(price, brackets.firstTime),
    rtb: calculateDuty(price, brackets.returning), 
    shb: calculateDuty(price, brackets.second), 
});

function calculateDuty(price, bracket) {
    var duty = 0, prevLevel = 0
    for (const rate of bracket) {
        if (rate.level <= price) {
            duty += (rate.level - prevLevel) * rate.tax;
            prevLevel = rate.level;
        } else {
            return duty + (price - prevLevel) * rate.tax;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done!  Separating data from policy is one of my favorite tricks for making things better.  Nicely explained, too.

Comment: @Blindman67 I really liked this solution. Very clean. I think I knew what I was doing wasn't best but was struggling to figure out how to split out the common functionality.

Answer (score 2):

In `stampDutyCalc` function you can avoid object mutation and just call your functions instead of putting the value `0`.

In calculation functions there is no need to use `+=` because only one `if` branch is evaluated. You can just use `return` instead, e.g. `return price * 0.05`.

Specific business rules of calculation are mixed with programming logic that makes them hard to understand and change.

I suggest using a data-driven design and represent business rules as data.
Here is the code for my solution:

```
const between = (from, to) => function (price) {
    return from <= price && price <= to;
}

const moreThan = (x) => function (price) {
    return price >= x;
}

const rules = {
    ftb: [
        [between(0, 300000), (price) => 0],
        [between(300001, 925000), (price) => price * 0.05],
        [between(925001, 1500000), (price) => (price - 925000) * 0.1 + (925000 - 300000) * 0.05],
        [moreThan(925001, 1500001), (price) => (price - 1500000) * 0.12 + (1500000 - 925000) * 0.1 + (925000 - 300000) * 0.05],
    ],
    rtb: [
        [between(0, 125000), (price) => 0],
        [between(125000, 250000), (price) => price * 0.02],
        [between(250001, 925000), (price) => (price - 250000) * 0.05 + (250000 - 125000) * 0.02],
        [between(925000, 1500000), (price) => (price - 925000) * 0.1 + (925000 - 250000) * 0.05 + (250000 - 125000) * 0.02],
        [moreThan(1500001), (price) => (price - 1500000) * 0.12 + (1500000 - 925000) * 0.1 + (925000 - 250000) * 0.05 + (250000 - 125000) * 0.02],
    ],
    shb: [
        // rules for shb
    ],
}

const getCalc = (rules) => function calc(price) {
    const calcFor = (type) => {
        const rule = rules[type];
        const noMatch = [true, () => 0];
        const [, calc] = rule.find(([match]) => match(price)) || noMatch;
        return { [type]: calc(price) };
    }

    return Object.keys(rules).reduce((result, type) => ({ ...result, ...calcFor(type) }), {});
}

const calc = getCalc(rules);

console.log(calc(1500001));
console.log(calc(250001));
```

Comment: Really like this solution, could please explain what the following line is doing exactly `return Object.keys(rules).reduce((result, type) => ({ ...result, ...calcFor(type) }), {});`

Comment: It takes keys of rules (`ftb`, `rtb`, `shb`) and for each rule makes an object, e.g. `{ ftb: 123 }`, by calculating result for each type of buyer. Then it merges them one by one in the resulting object using `reduce`, e.g. `{ ftb: 123, rtb: 222, shb: 11 }`.